# Python: Extract function with Pandas column ignoring regex that i've verified on regexr.com

Tags: python, regex, string, geocode

I have a column in a pandas data table that contains a string with the city and coordinates. I want to extract the coordinates

It should be a relatively simple exercise:

[image]

Here is the code that i'm using to do the extract:

```
p = r'(?P<latitude>-?\d+\.\d+).*?(?P<longitude>-?\d+\.\d+)'
data[['latitude', 'longitude']] = data['geocode_result'].str.extract(p, expand=True)
data
```

But as you can see from my column, in the screenshot, it's listing NaN

Here is the regex being verified that it's capturing:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious? I just want to grab the coordinates from geocode_result

Thanks

Comment: By the way, I know about the minus sign being missed out on the longitude. But I wanted to make it as simple as possible and the extract is still not pulling the latitude and longitude

Answer (score 2):

Your example is working for me, but the extracted type is a string which makes me suspect that whatever code you're using to generate the screenshot is getting tripped up by the value not being a float.

Try converting the values to float:

```
data[['latitude', 'longitude']] = data['geocode_result'].str.extract(p, expand=True).astype(float)
```

Comment: This is very confusing for me. I've tried converting the column to text before the extract, yet that drops the numbers for whatever reason :S

Comment: The 'geocode_result' column is of type string. Regular expression matching and extraction is an operation that takes text (i.e. a string) as input and generates text as output. In this case, because of the specific regular expressions you're using, we know that the resulting text, e.g. "5.534454", is a valid representation of a floating-point number. Therefore, we can convert the matched text to a float.  The missing piece of the puzzle is the code that's generating the screenshot. As I mentioned, it appears to be expecting a float value.

Comment: I have tried adding that add it's still returning NaN. I think you could be right, maybe it's the regex that looking for a digit, but the column's data isn't stored as that

Comment: I've copied your data to a csv, read it into a dataframe, extracted it, converted (as above), and printed the results as floating point numbers. It all works. If the problem still exists, it's likely in the reporting code.

Comment: I hate to be demanding, but could you try the package? https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

Comment: pip install geopy

Comment: data['geocode_result'] = [geolocator.geocode(x, timeout = 60) for x in data['ghana_city']]

Comment: So that takes whatever is listed in ghana_city and looks up the coordinates. This resulting column is the one that I can't lookup the coordinates for

Comment: I just tried writing to CSV then reading from CSV. Interestingly the coordinates are dropped when trying to write to CSV as well

Comment: The issue is that `geocode()` returns `<class 'geopy.location.Location'>`, not a string. This class has some various behaviors. In particular, the `__str__()` function only returns the address, which is why your coordinates disappear when converting to a string. Probably the easiest way to handle this is to wrap `repr()` around the result, i.e. `data['geocode_result'] = [repr(geolocator.geocode(x, timeout = 60)) for x in data['ghana_city']]`. Otherwise, you could explicitly extract the components. See https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/location.py for more info.